# Trouble with Inputting a Boolean in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a function that runs another function repeatedly until the user inputs "False" for the variable WhatIsLove, but no matter the input WhatIsLove returns as true. What is happening?

```
def DontHurtMeNoMore():
    WhatIsLove = bool(True)
    while bool(WhatIsLove) == True:
        print hexboi()
        WhatIsLove == bool(input("Would you like to run the program again? True or False: "))
```

Comment: you mean you need to break the program when user input `False` string?

Comment: Applying `bool()` to a string object (`str`) will always return `True` if it is not an empty string, `''`. Try this: `print(bool('False'))`. You'll get `True`. This is by design.

Comment: input() returns a string in python3 or raw input in python 2.7, so if your user inputs data, bool of that will always be true. then you're doing weird stuff in the last line -- you're not assigning to WhatIsLove, you're comparing it to the return value of bool(input(...))

Comment: I suggest this way: `while what_is_love.lower() in 't true'.split():` etc etc. Also: don't use camel case for variable names! Camel case is for classes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `input` returns a string, and strings always return `True`.

```
>>> bool('a')
True
>>> bool('False')
True
```

So, what you need to do is:

```
x = input("Would you like to run the program again? True or False: ")
if x.lower() == 'True':
    WhatIsLove = True
else:
    WhatIsLove = False
```

Comment: "strings always return `True`" Except for the empty string `""`, which is one cool thing from Python.

Answer (score 0):

**bool** doesn't convert the "display" value back to a boolean; it evaluates the expression.  Any string evaluates to a "Truthy" value of **True**, except for the null string, which you can't read with **input**.

You need to check the string's actual characters.  You might also want to get an innate understanding of booleans: your check is redundant.  Try this:

```
prompt = "Would you like to run the program again? True or False: "
def DontHurtMeNoMore():
    WhatIsLove = True
    while WhatIsLove:
        print hexboi()
        WhatIsLove = input(prompt) == "True"
```